# How to save .fla as .xfl by code?

Tags: flash, jsfl, xfl

I am using jsfl to save .fla Doc in flash.But I want to save as .xfl(uncompressed document format), and I can't find useful API in jsfl.What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:
    `fl.getDocumentDOM().saveAsCopy('PathURI / filename.xfl');`

Eg. If you'd like to save a fla file's copy as xfl in the same location and with same name, use this:

```
var newFileName = fl.getDocumentDOM().pathURI.replace('.fla','.xfl');
fl.getDocumentDOM().saveAsCopy(newFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just don't know the saveAsCopy can save as .xfl